# Concurrent Array Functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, array.prototype.map, sub-array

I have a function that takes an array of sub-arrays containing number strings and returns an array with the highest number from each sub-array:

```
const largestOfFour = arr => {
            arr.map(e => {
                e.sort((a,b) => b - a).splice(1);
            });
            return arr.flat();
        }
```

It works perfectly in the way it is formatted above but it does not work if it is formatted with concurrent functions on the array passed in. Like this:

```
const largestOfFour = arr => {
            return arr.map(e => {
                e.sort((a,b) => b - a).splice(1);
            }).flat();
        }
```

In that format it returns an array of appropriate length but each element is null. Can anyone help me understand why that is? I usually don't have a problem chaining concurrent functions onto an array.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "concurrent function", can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concurrency in JavaScript. But your `map` callback does not return anything (there is no `return` in the statement block) so `.map()` returns an array of undefined values.

To avoid that the original data gets mutated, I would also avoid the use of `sort` on the original array, and use `slice` instead of `splice`.

But as you only need *one* value from each array, you don't even need `slice`: just get the value at index 0 (making `flat` unnecessary):

```js
let a = [
  ["1", "2", "3"],
  ["4", "5", "6"]
];

const largestOfFour = arr =>
  arr.map(e =>
    [...e].sort((a, b) => b - a)[0]
  );

console.log(largestOfFour(a));
```

Or even better, just use `Math.max`, which also makes the conversion to number:

```js
let a = [
  ["1", "2", "3"],
  ["4", "5", "6"]
];

const largestOfFour = arr => arr.map(e => Math.max(...e));

console.log(largestOfFour(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner block (in map) issn't returning anything, resulting in an array of undefined.  Fixed in the snippet...

```js
let a = [
  ["1", "2", "3"],
  ["4", "5", "6"]
]

const largestOfFour = arr => {
  return arr.map(e => {
    return e.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
  }).flat();
}

console.log(largestOfFour(a))
```